# When it necessary to add "the" before Ruby Community

Tags: definite-articles

The community of the Ruby language has an issue, one of the main resources is not accessible. So I wrote a message in the GitHub:

> Ruby Koans is a real treasure of Ruby Community, best way to get into Ruby development in a short time.

Do I need to add 'the' before 'Ruby Community', and by the way what is a correct way?

> So I wrote a message in the GitHub.
> So I wrote a message in GitHub.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of correct usage here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Github* is a proper name, so it doesn't need *the*.

If *Ruby Community* is a proper name (i.e., the word *community* is really capitalized), you don't need *the*. If it's just a community described by *Ruby*, you need the word *the*.

Comment: Some singular proper nouns/names require a definite article (eg the Eiffel Tower, the Louvre, the Pacific, the Med, the Nile, the South Pole, the Tropic of Cancer, the Alps ...). _She works for **the** Admiralty_. Others disallow the definite article (_He plays for Chelsea / Wales_) Others are variable  (_He plays for [the] Arsenal_). How is one to know without checking actual usage?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, it is looks like the answer is "as you wish" or "it is up to you" :) you could add **"the"** and could do not to add **"the"**.

Comment: No, Dmitry. English is often unpredictable, but the general rule of thumb is 'do what most seasoned native speakers in your area do'.